Roboflow cv2.imshow error keeps occurring even though it worked yesterday. How to fix?
I am constantly getting this error:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
I have gone through all the other fixes for this, which actually worked for a day and then didn't (such as updating the version to name/version#). But now, even after not changing the code, I am getting the error again.
Here is sections of my code:
upload_url = "".join([
    "https://detect.roboflow.com/",
    "basketball-cv/3",
    "?api_key=",
    "*************",
    "&format=image",
    "&stroke=5"
])

async def infer(requests):
    # Get the current image from the webcam
    ret, img = video.read()

    # Resize (while maintaining the aspect ratio) to improve speed and save bandwidth
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))

    # Encode image to base64 string
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)

    # Get prediction from Roboflow Infer API
    resp = await requests.post(upload_url, data=img_str, headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    })

    # Parse result image
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.content), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image
...

 cv2.imshow('image', image)

What is the issue?
I tried changing version number, updating the Size and API key

run this in a debugger. image is None or something else that's not a numpy array -- [mre] links to a debugging tutorial

"What is the issue?" -- for one, total lack of any attempt at error handling. You store couple of result codes in variables, only to ignore them, and happily chug along as if nothing could ever fail. Most likely resp.content doesn't contain what you think it does, causing imdecode to fail. Hard to say without more details.

@ChristophRackwitz and @DanMašek already provided some hints:

you are not checking if video.read() returned a frame, assuming video is instance of cv2.VideoCapture you should check ret before assuming method returned a frame as OpenCV documentation suggests

you are not inspecting response returned by requests.post


I would also add that it's difficult to reason about example code you provided, it seems video is a global variable and it might be closed elsewhere in the code before script execution even reached infer. Your camera might not be connected, you don't show how VideoCapture is opened as this is where you should handle these problems. Also making requests for each frame will probably not keep up with frames flowing from camera, as example solution you might want to buffer frames from camera and drop frames while waiting for results of requests.
You could consider refactoring your code slightly so it's easier for you to reason where the problem is:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests


ROBOFLOW_SIZE = 500


class ReadingFrameFailed(Exception):
    pass


class SerializingFrameFailed(Exception):
    pass


class RequestsPostFailed(Exception):
    pass


class MalformedResponse(Exception):
    pass


# (...)


async def infer(
    video: cv2.VideoCapture,
    model_id,
    roboflowapi_key,
    requests: ????,
    upload_url_template: str = "https://detect.roboflow.com/{model_id}?api_key={roboflow_api_key}&format=image&stroke=5",
) -> np.array:
    ret, img = video.read()

    if not ret:
        raise ReadingFrameFailed("Failed to grab frame")

    height, width, *_ = img.shape
    scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))

    # Encode image to base64 string
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    if not retval:
        raise SerializingFrameFailed("Failed to serialize frame")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)


    upload_url = upload_url_template.format(**{
        "model_id": model_id,
        "roboflow_api_key": roboflow_api_key,
    })

    try:
        resp = await requests.post(upload_url, data=img_str,
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    except Exception as exc:
        # ugly but since we don't know what `requests` object is...
        raise RequestsPostFailed(str(exc))

    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.content), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if not image:
        raise MalformedResponse("Failed to parse image, API returned unexpected result")

    return image

